# My root directory (/) is owned by my user. Shouldn't it be owned by root?

Tags: permissions, chown

When I run `ls -la /`, it shows that `.` and `..` are owned by my user, and are my user group.

I am almost positive that `/` should be owned by root and that I must have accidentally chowned `/` but it's been surprisingly difficult to Google for who the proper owner of `/` should be and I don't want to break anything by changing it to root.

Comment: Yes, it ought to be owned by root, and its permissions should be `drwxr.xr.x`. If the contents of the / folder are OK I don't think it would break anything if you changed it back to root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ownership of / is root:root, so UID=0, GID=0.

Same ownership (root:root) typically applies to absolutely everything directly under / (e.g. /bin, /etc, /home, /var)